# VB .NET - Error copy datagridview (datatable) value to array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I already succeeded in made local database using datatable and it was displayed in datagridview. But I want to copy the values to array so I can process it in other code.

For example

```
coba(0,0) = data in datagridviewResources column 0 row 0

coba(0,1) = data in datagridviewresources column 0 row 1
```

But I got the error :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

My code:

```
Dim table As New DataTable("Table")
Dim index As Integer
Dim coba(100, 100) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    table.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Filename", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Column", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    datagridviewResources.DataSource = table
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim newDataRow As DataGridViewRow
    newDataRow = datagridviewResources.Rows(index)
    newDataRow.Cells(0).Value = txtID.Text
    newDataRow.Cells(1).Value = txtFilename.Text
    newDataRow.Cells(2).Value = txtColumn.Text
End Sub

Private Sub datagridviewResources_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles datagridviewResources.CellClick
    index = e.RowIndex
    Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
    selectedRow = datagridviewResources.Rows(index)
    txtID.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    txtFilename.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
    txtColumn.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    datagridviewResources.Rows.RemoveAt(index)
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    table.Rows.Add(txtID.Text, txtFilename.Text, txtColumn.Text)
    datagridviewResources.DataSource = table
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click, datagridviewResources.SelectionChanged
    For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count
        For j = 0 To table.Columns.Count
            coba(i,j) = datagridviewResources.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString())
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: @Slai Ah yes - and possibly on the next line as well. Nice one.